# Get certain text from website using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I'm trying to copy a certain string of a website's source code using selenium.

**This is the page's source code:**

```
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">{"url":"https:\/\/shop.website.com\/cart\/12260378345553:1?step=payment_method&amp;key=874a4c1e464f7d8fb61465c6fdb63a69aeb536fa490a66f66d37395f4cfce98e"}</body>
```

I would like selenium to grab the link seen after the "url": part. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the string between `{"url":` and `}`. Use [str.Find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to find the position of the substring you need.

```
str = '<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">{"url":"https:\/\/shop.website.com\/cart\/12260378345553:1?step=payment_method&amp;key=874a4c1e464f7d8fb61465c6fdb63a69aeb536fa490a66f66d37395f4cfce98e"}</body>'
substr = str[str.find("{\"url\":")+7 : str.find("}")]
print(substr)
```

**Output:**

```
"https:\/\/shop.website.com\/cart\/12260378345553:1?step=payment_method&amp;key=874a4c1e464f7d8fb61465c6fdb63a69aeb536fa490a66f66d37395f4cfce98e"
```